# create set of randomized column names in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a set of columns (within panda dataframe) where the column names are randomized. This is because I want to generate filter data from a larger data-set in a randomized fashion.

How can I generate an N (= 4) * 3 set of column names as per below?

```
    car_speed   state_8 state_17    state_19    state_16    wd_8    wd_17   wd_19   wd_16   wu_8    wu_17   wu_19   wu_16
```

My potential code below, but doesn't really work. I need the blocks'state_' first, then 'wd_', and then 'wd_'. My code below generates 'state_', 'wd_', 'wu_' individually in consecutive order. I have problems further on, when it is in that order, of filling in the data from the larger data-set

```
def iteration1(data, classes = 50, sigNum = 4):
    dataNN = pd.DataFrame(index = [0])
    dataNN['car_speed'] = np.zeros(1)
    while len(dataNN.columns) < sigNum + 1:
        state = np.int(np.random.uniform(0, 50))
        dataNN['state_'+str(state)] = np.zeros(1) # this is the state value set-up
        dataNN['wd_' + str(state)] = np.zeros(1) # this is the weight direction
        dataNN['wu_' + str(state)] = np.zeros(1) # this is the weight magnitude

    count = 0 # initialize count row as zero
    while count < classes :
        dataNN.loc[count] = np.zeros(len(dataNN.columns))
        for state in dataNN.columns[1:10]:
            dataNN[state].loc[count] = data[state].loc[count]
        count = count + 1
        if count > classes : break
    return dataNN
```

Comment: Please be specific about what "does not really work". Otherwise, nobody will be able to help you....

Comment: i updated my question, on what 'does not really work'. It is to do with the fact, I need the columns to be in 'blocks', rather than consecutively 'state_1', 'wd_1', wu_1' ....

Comment: Then my suspicion was right and the answer should satisfy your need. The key point is to move picking random ints out from the `while` loop body.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the problem you have is lack of grouping of `"state_*"`, `"wd_*"`, and `"wu_*"` I suggest that you first select `sigNum / 3` random ints and then use them to label the columns. Like the following:

```
states = [np.int(np.random.uniform(0, 50)) for _ in range (sigNum/3)]
i = 0
while len(dataNN.columns) <= sigNum:
    state = states[i]
    i += 1
    dataNN['state_'+str(state)] = np.zeros(1) # this is the state value set-up
    dataNN['wd_' + str(state)] = np.zeros(1) # this is the weight direction
    dataNN['wu_' + str(state)] = np.zeros(1) # this is the weight magnitude
```

Comment: hi @sophros, I tried your code but it still saves them in the form [state_, wd_, wu_]. I tried adjusting based on your code, and I think the one I would post below works.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
import pandas as pd

def iteration1(data, classes = 5, subNum = 15):
    dataNN = pd.DataFrame(index = [0])
    dataNN['car_speed'] = np.zeros(1)

    states = random.sample(range(50), sub_sig)
    for i in range(0, sub_sig, 1):
        dataNN['state_'+str(states[i])] = np.zeros(1) # this is the state value set-up
    for i in range(0, subNum, 1):
        dataNN['wd_' + str(states[i])] = np.zeros(1) # this is the weight direction
    for i in range(0, subNum, 1):
        dataNN['wu_' + str(states[i])] = np.zeros(1) # this is the weight magnitude

    return dataNN
```